# Hook to create branch from latest develop

Tags: git, github, branch, checkout, githooks

I'm looking for a git hook that can help me with the current problem, when i create new branch i want first to pull the latest develop version and after that to create that x branch from latest develop. Unfortunately from what i know there are not pre-branch hooks. I want that because in our team sometimes we forget to take latest develop branch when we create new branch.

Comment: This is frought with the potential problem that the pull may cause a merge conflict (unless you are certain this would never happen with your workflow).

Comment: I don't think i can have merge conflict when i pull, because the new branch is created from develop but i want to be sure that my team is creating every new branch from latest develop.

Comment: Can you just create a new command ? If you create a script `git-<command>` and it's in your path, it can be invoked via `git <command>`. Say your group is FXX and your development tools are known as FYY, then you could call it `git fyybranch` and that would be a script that fetches from the appropriate remote, figures out the right place to branch off of, and creates the branch.